# How to get unpublished kernel updates?

Tags: wireless, kernel, keyboard, updates, apple

http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=commitdiff;h=652aa6a9ac4a5f8d3e1fa3f6466646519e83c01e

The above link has the device ids of apple's keyboards added to the kernel, which will allow for the use of the much needed `fn` key.

Is there anyway to force update the kernel with those patches, or create a custom kernel with those patches? There doesn't seem to be a release date, and I can barely understand that page as it is.

Ubuntu 11.10

Kernel 3.0.0-15-generic

Comment: What version of ubuntu, or better what kernel are you running ? It looks as if that patch was applied to the stable kernel on "Fri, 9 Dec 2011" http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=commitdiff;h=652aa6a9ac4a5f8d3e1fa3f6466646519e83c01e  If you want to know about how the kernel archives "work"  (git and patches) take a look at this : http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/development-process/2.Process but I hope we can solve your problem without necessarily explaining all that to you all at once =)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I have added the kernel version. Sorry for taking so long, I forgot about updating this post.

Answer (score 1):

This fix is actually the patch below, which was part of the 3.3 release (3.3-rc1 was its first appearance):

```
commit 652aa6a9ac4a5f8d3e1fa3f6466646519e83c01e
Author: Jeremy Fitzhardinge <jeremy@goop.org>
Date:   Fri Dec 9 00:10:28 2011 -0800

    hid-input/battery: add FEATURE quirk
```

As this patch is not marked as a stable patch it would not normally be applied routinely to older releases.  If this fix does fix an issue for you you could submit it to the Ubuntu kernel team, the easiest way would be to file a bug against the `linux` package and describe the issue, then send the patch to kernel-team@lists.ubuntu.com referencing the bug for consideration.

See 'Submitting a Patch to the Ubuntu Kernel' section of the wiki page below for more details on the process:

```
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Dev/KernelPatches
```